# Netlify page not found with react-typescript webpack app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redirect, webpack, netlify

I'm trying to build and deploy a webpack react-ts app which works fine when displaying the home page, but will not properly display any routes. I have the `_redirects` file in my public folder and set configurations in `webpack.config.js` Am I missing something here?

folder structure

```bash
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   ├── index.html
│   └── _redirects # I added the redirects file so netlify doesn't throw 404s
├── scripts
│   ├── gc.sh
│   └── gp.sh
├── src
│   ├── App.tsx
│   ├── components
│   ├── entry.tsx
│   └── pages
│       ├── About
│       │   ├── helper.ts
│       │   └── index.tsx
│       └── Home
│           ├── helper.ts
│           └── index.tsx
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/entry.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
  devServer:{
    historyApiFallback: true // Are there any additional configuration properties I am missing?
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html')
    })
  ]
}
``
```